# How do I provide a value to a service from a unit test in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have a unit test for my application that test once of the services I've written.  The service itself makes another call to a different service to grab some information and the tests fails at this point hitting an object reference exception.

Here is my test method:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public async Task CarPayments_Should_Return_200_If_Account_NotNull()
 {
     CarPaymentModel carPayment = new()
     {
         CarPrice = "19995"
     };
     var userAccount = "423"
     var carPaymentRespond = await _serviceTest.CarPayment(carPayment, userAccount);
     Assert.IsNotNull(carPaymentRespond );
 }
```

When the `_serviceTest.CarPayment` is called, there is an account check in there that throws an error of:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

This occurs when the userAccount null check is performed, after debugging the test I can see that the userAccount is indeed null.  Given that I provide a value user account value I don't know why this is happening.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CarPayment(string carPrice, string userAccount)
{
        try
        { 
            //Should this be handled in this way?
            var dealershipAccount = await dealershipClient.GetDealershipUser(userAccount);

            if (userAccount is null)//throws error object reference is null on userAccount
            {
                ...whatever
            }
        }
     ...
}
```

Is my setup wrong for this?  Is there another way I should be accessing that account?

Comment: A unit-test tests the logic of the code in question without any dependencies. What you have here is an integration test. That being said, it sounds like  some logic `_serviceTest` is not passing the `userAccount` on to the subsequent service.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. It would also be awesome if you could reformat the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: We are missing too many unknown variables in both the test and subject under test to be able to provide you the assistance you seek.